# Is there any possibilities to send form from fields backend to frontend with rest API?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to send form from fields backend to front-end with rest API?

I tried to write form by myself in front-end, but it wasn’t a best practice. I want to get input Fields with API, so I can render it right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to do it but you can send sth like this to front-end

```
[{
    type:”input”,
    placeholder:”name”,
    default_value:”some_value_you_got_from_database”,
    label:”name”,
    Key:”sample-keyname-to-send-to-back”
},
{
    type:”select”,
    placeholder:”country”,
    default_value:”some_value_you_got_from_database”,
    label:”country”,
    Key:”sample-keyname-to-send-to-back”
}]
```

Then you can conditionally render custom input components for type input and custome select components when you have the value of select in your response.
It goes on for other type of form fields.